# Refreshing the grand parent page

Tags: javascript, window.open

Problem statement

1) I have a page A which opens a popup B using window.open().

2) B collect some user info and send it to the java controller which after processing returns a redirect url to B.

3) B then opens this redirect url(www.temp.com/qq/rr.jsp) using window.open('www.temp.com/qq/rr.jsp',_self).

4) at www.temp.com/qq/rr.jsp ,user performs some action and once it completes , www.temp.com/qq/rr.jsp calls page B.

5) Once B is called ,based on some condition, this popup (page B) should be closed and page A should be replaced with page D.

[image]

I am not able to replace page A with D using window.opener.location.href.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to preserve the window opener.  Once they navigate away, this is lost.  The trick, is to always navigate by using the parent window.  Instead of window.open, you are going to call the parent window, and tell IT to change the location of the child window.

In page A:

```
var b = window.open('b.html');
function setChildWindowLocation(href) {
    b.location.href = href;
}
```

In page B:

```
function getRedirectUrl() {
  var href = ajax(); //this is obviously psuedo-code for getting the redirect url
  window.opener.setChildWindowLocation(href);
}

function checkCondition(condition) {
  if (condition) 
  {
    //this will work, because we still have an opener
    window.opener.location.href = 'D.html'; 
    window.close();
  }
}
```

In page RR:

```
function goBackToPageB() {
  window.opener.setChildWindowLocation('B.html');
}
```